# Automatic page refresh stops working (Flask App)

Tags: python, html, flask, page-refresh

I created a Flask app that displays the latest pictures on an HTML website. The website is set to automatically refresh every 10 seconds using a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

it all works great when the server and website run on a local PC, but when I run the app over LAN, the page refreshes correctly a few times, but sooner or later it stops. The webpage itself looks like it is loading (spinning wheel), but no new requests are registered in the flask app. The only way to start refreshing it again is by manual refresh on the client-side or by restarting the flask app on the server-side.

What could be the problem that causes this and how to mitigate it? Can it be caused by a firewall that doesn't like the constant refreshes? Are there any alternatives to said meta tag? I don't want to have any difficult set-up on the client-side like job scheduling etc (unless it is the only solution).

Comment: Did you try to use Inspector/Developer Tools in your browser? It will tell you what your browser thinks about that.

Comment: I am not sure what am I supposed to look for. There is no error, the browser is stuck "loading" the web page, but the server doesn't register any request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use javascript for this. Just put the code below in your html file somewhere or in a seperate javascript file named `script.js`  and link that javascript file like `<script src="/Path/To/File.js"></script>`

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.reload();
}, 30000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly without any issues.

Comment: No prob :) wanna upvote so i can finally have the privilege of commenting on any post ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I would love to, but I don't have the reputation for it yet :( sorry

Comment: oh ok. I answered a question last night an got the rep. Thanks though. Now i have 50 and im honestly so happy :)